# Pivot table with custom Name as columnNames

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

How can i pivot a table with single column.

result set of my select query contains single column and 3 rows.
i.e my select query looks like :-

```
contactList table have following columns.
ContactID, PhNumbers, PhTYpe, ContactPersonID

select PhNumbers,PhType from contactList where ContactPersonID=3

PhNumbers     PhType
1234567890      1
3456789013      2
4545466756      3
```

these 3 rows corresponds to 3 types of phone numbers

i need an output like this

```
homePhone     MobilePhone     WorkPhone
1234567890    3456789013      4545466756
```

Comment: What is the server version? Only the three type of phones allowed? How to decide which of them of what type?

Comment: yes. In contactList I have phoneType Also. can i do anything with PhoneType. ?

Comment: Need more info. Show schemes of tables. Also add sql server version.

Comment: Join the table with a table that contains the descriptions for types, to resolve the description for the type, then do the pivot...

Comment: Got answer. Check for my answer below. Thanks for yous guidance and help.

Comment: My answer is usefull or not if it is usefull then mark it as accept. -Sahi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer. Thanks for all your help guys.

```
SELECT [1] as HomePhone, [2] as MobilePhone,[3] as WorkPhone,
FROM
  (select PhNumbers,PhType from contactList where ContactPersonID=3) AS     SourceTable
PIVOT
(
MAX(PhNumbers)
FOR PhType IN ([1],[2],[3])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: I have used aggregate function here. is there alternative for this. any help suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
  DECLARE
    @SQL varchar(MAX),
    @ColumnList varchar(MAX)

SELECT @ColumnList=
       COALESCE(@ColumnList + ',','') + QUOTENAME(PhNumbers)
FROM
(
       SELECT DISTINCT PhNumbers
       FROM contactList 
) T


SET @SQL = '
WITH PivotData AS
(
       SELECT PhNumbers
       FROM contactList
)
SELECT
    ' + @ColumnList + '
FROM
    PivotData
PIVOT
(
    MAX(PhNumbers)
    FOR PhNumbers
    IN (' + @ColumnList + ')
) AS PivotResult'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

SELECT 1,2,3
FROM
(SELECT PhNumbers, PhType
  FROM contactList where ContactPersonID=3) a
 PIVOT(MAX(PhNumbers) FOR PhType IN(1,
2,
3)) r